# Does AWS codebuild support proxy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Is there a way we can use all the public resources that awscodebuild need access to (such as AWS CodeCommit, GitHub, Bitbucket), Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) to deliver build artifacts, and Amazon CloudWatch Logs ) without attaching a NAT or IGW? Does aws code build support proxy?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/use-proxy-server.html

You shouldn't need NAT gateway, with a proxy setup in your VPC. I assume your setup has VPC, based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to have access to AWS's service via AWS internal network then you can refer to AWS VPC Endpoints service which is used to connect to service such as S3 within AWS internal network

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints.html